# Is Bind an XamlType in http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml?

Tags: c++-winrt

(I'm not using Visual Studio)
why following page got error `The type 'Bind' was not found. [Line: 3 Position: 10]`

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button Content="{x:Bind nothing}"/>
</Page>
```

many thanks!

Comment: When you declare `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`, you could use x:bind to do binding operation in Visual Studio. Can you tell us which tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using EWDK , there is no code-behind , so, I think I have to implement the IXamlMetadataProvider and IXamlType myself , is this the right way ?

Comment: Can you provide a download link about EWDK for us? Did this error occur when you compiled the above code snippet? Can you show the specific steps for us?

Comment: 1. ewdk is from https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/legal/windows/hardware/enterprise-wdk-license-2019

Comment: 2. the error is reported by catch Xaml parsing exception ```struct MainPage : PageT<MainPage>
{
  MainPage()
  {
    try 
    {
      Application::LoadComponent(*this, Uri(L"ms-appx:///MainPage.xaml"));  
    }
    catch(hresult_error e)
    {
      wcout << hex << e.code() << dec << " : " << (wstring_view)e.message() << endl;
    } } }```

Comment: A page containing x:Bind is never supposed to reach LoadComponent. The Xaml Compiler is parsing all x:Bind first, generating code for it, and then stripping them all out in what we call a re-written Xaml file. These files are placed in the project's intermediate output directory (obj) and are what we expect LoadComponent to get (they look just like the original xaml files but they have xome extra x:ComponentId attributes and they have no x:Binds). The UWP build does that stripping automatically. So why you get an original Xaml file down to LoadComponent? Are you rolling a Xaml build by hand?

Comment: thanks for reply.  by ```re-written``` , I think the page will be converted to something like ```<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:y="using:App">
    <Button Content="{y:BindImpl nothing}"/>
</Page>``` , It seems make sense !